# How to run Chrome headless with noproxy on Linux?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, headless

Running Selenium with ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88 on Linux (CetOS7) in headless mode.

I know that not all networking features are supported in headless mode, but running without any proxy feels like it should be. Basically I have two options to run:

1. Using PAC file, which is not support in headless mode right now [Chromium Issue 765245](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765245)
2. Disable proxy explicitly, running curl with `--noproxy` flag works

So far I tried following options to disable the proxy:

- `--proxy-server="direct://"` Chrome won't even start
- `--no-proxy-server` getting a message that "The Host is not resolvable."

Is there some other way to disable the proxy?

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032878/disable-proxy-via-python-for-selenium-with-headless-chrome) recommends using `chrome_options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, flag `--no-proxy-server` works for me only in UI mode, but if I go headless then I am getting "The host is not resolvable"

Comment: (1) Are you using Chrome or Chromium? The proxy parameters are better supported in Chromium. (2) Try the http proxy environment variable `no_proxy` which contains patterns for IP addresses or domain names that shouldn’t use the proxy. Ensure that you don't have set `http_proxy` or `https_proxy`. See [this article](https://blog.testproject.io/2018/02/20/chrome-headless-selenium-python-linux-servers/) for useful information. (3) Ensure that the proxy is not set system-wide.

Comment: (1) I'm using `Google Chrome 87.0.4280.88`, will give a Chromium try
(2) I did had `http(s)_proxy` set, after unstetig variables it almost works with `--proxy-server="direct://"` page is loaded but it needs 2.5 minutes to do it and after 1 minute Chromedriver is timing out, with headless Firefox it works immediately
(3) Probably it is not system-wide setting, since it works in Firefox and cURL

Answer (score 1):

I've also run into this issue and it appears that `--no-proxy-server` is not supported when in headless mode. See Chromium Issue [829247](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=829247)

The workaround I've found is passing these two flags to Chrome along with `--headless`

```
--proxy-server='direct://'
```

And:

```
--proxy-bypass-list=*
```

After passing these flags Chrome ignores the system proxy settings and as far as I've tested they work on my test machine.  `--proxy-server='direct://'` alone doesn't appear to be enough to get this to work, you need both flags set.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just adding this:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).